# Magento 2 when import CSV product how to convert utf8 to Shift_JIS

Tags: magento2, import, csv

In Magento 2 when import CSV product how to convert utf8 to Shift_JIS.
How to do this ? please show me detail if you can.

Comment: Exactly problem is error font "???"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solution and worked!.

I encoded my **CSV file to uft8**.

Comment: But I until want to encode by Plugin. So, anyone know how to develop: encode from "Shift_JIS" to "UTF8" , when import product CSV file ?